# laravel, substring in groupby()

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would group selected column by orderBy without last 3 character from cars.name.

```
$objects_collection = $objects_collection
        ->groupBy("cars.name", "parts.part_catalog_id", "parts.colour_id")
        ->select($this->getProperTableName(str_plural($this->getRoute())) . ".*", DB::raw("count(*) as quantity"))
        ->paginate($paginate);
```

How should I do it ?

Edit:

**SOLUTION** is:

```
$objects_collection = $objects_collection
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(cars.name, '/', 1)"), "parts.part_catalog_id", "parts.colour_id")
        ->select($this->getProperTableName(str_plural($this->getRoute())) . ".*", DB::raw("count(*) as quantity"))
        ->paginate($paginate);
```

Comment: not sure what you're doing, but groupBy can have a callback https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-groupby

Comment: this work on collection, but I want do it in request to database

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like (didn't tested it)

```
$objects_collection = $objects_collection
        ->groupBy(substr($objects_collection->cars.name, 0, -3), "parts.part_catalog_id", "parts.colour_id")
        ->select($this->getProperTableName(str_plural($this->getRoute())) . ".*", DB::raw("count(*) as quantity"))
        ->paginate($paginate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL you can give a try with:

```
$objects_collection = $objects_collection
    ->groupBy("cars.name", "parts.part_catalog_id", "parts.colour_id")
    ->select(DB::raw('SUBSTR(`cars.name`, 1, (LENGTH(`cars.name`)-3))'), $this->getProperTableName(str_plural($this->getRoute())) . ".*", DB::raw("count(*) as quantity"))
    ->orderByRaw('1')'
    ->paginate($paginate);
```

As you said that you want to `orderBy`.